# They are more accepting to this concept

Tags: grammaticality

> They are more **accepting** to the idea of John rather than the idea of Peter.
>
> They are more **acceptance** to the idea of John rather than the idea of Peter.

What I wanted to say is that they could accept the idea of John better, compared to the idea of Peter. Which sentences above are grammatical and have made a right usage?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is just plain wrong. "Acceptance" is a noun meaning the condition of having accepted: people are not conditions. Even if "they" does not refer to people, what is grammatical is "They are acceptances ..."

The first sentence **may** not violate any formal rule of English grammar, but it is not idiomatic, at least not in the U.S. The preposition "of" is the normal usage with "accepting" rather than "to."

> They are more accepting of the idea of John than the idea of Peter

is grammatical and idiomatic, but it is awkward.

> They accept the idea of John better than the idea of Peter

expresses the same thought in a simpler and therefore more readily comprehensible form.

Finally, it is unclear what is even meant by the "idea" of a human being. It may be clear in context. Presumably what is meant is some supposition about their future actions or conditions. If context does not make it clear, then the supposition should be specified.

> They accept the idea that John will go to medical school more easily than the idea that Peter will.

**MAJOR EDIT**: The idiom "accept the idea of X" means "find most plausible the concept involving X." As a matter of English grmmar, the "idea of X" may also mean "the idea held or expressed by X" if X is a human being. To avoid that potential ambiguity, a native speaker would use the possessive to express "the idea held by person X." If that was what you are trying to convey, you should write

> They accept John's idea rather than Peter's.

Comment: "John's idea" would be more natural than "the idea of John".

Comment: @Accumulation Yes indeed **if what is being discussed** is a comparison of John's idea about X and Peter's idea about X. The possessive is so natural in that case that its absence meant that the meaning you mentioned simply did not occur to me. Rather I read them as comparing ideas **about** John and Peter as you can see from my suggestion about John's going to medical school. Thank yoo. I shall edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

By a large margin, *of* is favored over *to* as the preposition starting a complement following the gerund *accepting*. (By **complement**, I mean the thing that someone is accepting.) The Ngram viewer says about 15:1 in favor of the word *of*; the Corpus of Contemporary American English, 50:1. (This does not take into consideration the many false drops for *to* in the example texts.)

When *to* appears, most often it does so in a *to*-infinitive to indicate a task that someone is agreeing to undertake. From *A Guide to the ICC Rules of Arbitration* by Y Derains and ‎E A Schwartz (2005), p. 141:

> By *accepting **to serve***, every arbitrator undertakes to carry out his responsibilities in accordance with these Rules.

When the following *to* begins a prepositional phrase as the complement, *accepting* usually has the connotation of tolerance and openness. From *The Complete Idiot's Guide to the Talmud* (2004) by A Parry:

> Judaism is remarkably *accepting **to the notion*** of multiple paths to God.

When *accepting* means adopting as valid, a following prepositional phrase almost always has *of* as the preposition.